# Magento 2 layout XML reference block added in CMS page

Tags: magento2, module, layout, template

I have a CMS page, and in certain place it references a custom block from my module as such:

```
{{block class="My\Notification\Block\NotificationForm" name="notification.form" template="My_Notification::form.phtml"}}
```

This works and shows the template, but I don't know how to define child block within this template. In my module I have `view/frontend/layout/default.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="notification.form">
            <block name="notification.form.inner" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="My_Notification::inner.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

and in my `form.phtml` I have

```
...
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('notification.form.inner') ?>
...
```

but it just doesn't show up. I tried various other things, including trying to use `addChild()` in my block class constructor, but no matter what I try it just doesn't show up. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, turns out the block can just be defined directly in `form.phtml` template using the following code:

```
<?php 
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template')->setTemplate('My_Notification::inner.phtml');
echo $block->toHtml();
?>
```